# Selection of text and highlight giving error (Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node)

Tags: javascript

I am highlighting text based on selection. things are working fine but in some cases, it's giving error `" Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node"`.

I don't know why this error is below is the code I am using. Got stuck any help will be much appreciated.

```
var s = window.getSelection();
var pos;

var start,end, range;
function highlight(element,st,en){
    range = document.createRange();
   
    start = st;
    end = en;
    pos = 0;
    dig(element);
    s.removeAllRanges();
    s.addRange(range);
    var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);
}


function dig(el){
    $(el).contents().each(function(i,e){
        if (e.nodeType==1){
            // not a textnode
         dig(e);
        }else{
            if (pos<start){
               if (pos+e.length>=start){
                range.setStart(e, start-pos);
               }
            }
            if (pos<end){
               if (pos+e.length>=end){
                range.setEnd(e, end-pos);
               }
            }
            pos = pos+e.length;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what does `dig` do?

Comment: dig calculate the range from start and endpoints.I have edited the question please check now. May you get some help.